# How to take Integration?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving a differential Equation using Bernoulli's Equation.
I found Integrating factor, then I multiplied with the whole equation, and then I applied Integration both sides.

$\frac{x(1-x^2)^{-1/4}}{2}$

I am stuck now, I always get stuck with these kind of equations. Please I need help. Thanks!!

PS. Sorry about the Formatting, i've edited it now.

Comment: my answer holds. My sign in the denominator of $-1/4$ was a typo; this has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are seeking to solve $\frac{x}{2(1-x^2)^{1/4}}$. You should set $u = -x^2$ and evaluate $-1/4\cdot \frac{du}{(1+u)^{1/4}} = -1/4\cdot 4/3\cdot (1+u)^{3/4} = -\frac{(1-x^2)^{3/4}}{3} + c$. Substitution is a common "trick" when solving problems of the form $\frac{P(x,n-1)\; dx}{P(x,n)}$, where the second variable is the degree of the polynomial $P$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now i've edited my question properly. Sorry for the trouble.